# Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`. x Problem with `summarise()` input in R when conduct regression

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have this dataset.

```
 dat=structure(list(sku = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), period = c("30.09.2021", 
        "14.03.2019", "01.04.2022", "18.02.2022", "07.07.2021", "09.10.2020", 
        "17.01.2019", "10.11.2020", "14.07.2021", "10.09.2019", "31.01.2019", 
        "01.07.2021", "30.09.2021", "14.03.2019", "01.04.2022", "18.02.2022", 
        "07.07.2021", "09.10.2020", "17.01.2019", "10.11.2020", "14.07.2021", 
        "10.09.2019", "31.01.2019", "01.07.2021"), hist.prices = c(3728.16, 
        34899.84, 6126, 1789.44, 18098.4, 15633.6, 26174.88, 2401.56, 
        12668.88, 239500.8, 26174.88, 5429.52, 3728.16, 34899.84, 6126, 
        1789.44, 18098.4, 15633.6, 26174.88, 2401.56, 12668.88, 239500.8, 
        26174.88, 5429.52), hist.revenue = c(178951.68, 20102307.84, 
        367560, 42946.56, 4343616, 3752064, 11307548.16, 86456.16, 2128371.84, 
        965667225.6, 11307548.16, 390925.44, 178951.68, 20102307.84, 
        367560, 42946.56, 4343616, 3752064, 11307548.16, 86456.16, 2128371.84, 
        965667225.6, 11307548.16, 390925.44), hist.demand = c(254L, 276L, 
        272L, 250L, 299L, 297L, 291L, 260L, 270L, 275L, 295L, 279L, 254L, 
        276L, 272L, 250L, 299L, 297L, 291L, 260L, 270L, 275L, 295L, 279L
        ), hist.cost = c(12572.6698, 10498.9848, 14949.392, 13160.5, 
        14557.9512, 12443.3199, 10692.3294, 10893.116, 13145.976, 10222.6025, 
        10982.9975, 13584.1752, 12572.6698, 10498.9848, 14949.392, 13160.5, 
        14557.9512, 12443.3199, 10692.3294, 10893.116, 13145.976, 10222.6025, 
        10982.9975, 13584.1752), unity.cost = c(49.4987, 38.0398, 54.961, 
        52.642, 48.6888, 41.8967, 36.7434, 41.8966, 48.6888, 37.1731, 
        37.2305, 48.6888, 49.4987, 38.0398, 54.961, 52.642, 48.6888, 
        41.8967, 36.7434, 41.8966, 48.6888, 37.1731, 37.2305, 48.6888
        ), hist.profit = c(1336L, 1592L, 1128L, 1882L, 1387L, 1818L, 
        1357L, 1087L, 1253L, 1009L, 1092L, 1804L, 1336L, 1592L, 1128L, 
        1882L, 1387L, 1818L, 1357L, 1087L, 1253L, 1009L, 1092L, 1804L
        )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -24L))
```

i decided conduct simple regression in such way. (provided below code works on this little dataset)

```
library(dplyr)
library(nplyr)
library(tidyr)

p=dat$hist.prices
true.revenue = function(p) p*(-alpha*p + beta) # Revenue with true parameters (chunck demand)
true.profit = function(p) (p - unity.cost)*(-alpha*beta + 500) # price with true parameters
# estimated curves
```

so when i run this code

```
dat1=dat %>% 
  nest(data = -sku) %>% 
  nest_summarise(data, 
                 model.fit = list(lm(hist.demand ~ hist.prices)), 
                 beta = model.fit[[1]]$coefficients[1], 
                 alpha = model.fit[[1]]$coefficients[2],
                 p.revenue = -beta/(2*alpha),
                 p.profit = (alpha*unity.cost - beta)/(2*alpha),
                 opt.revenue = true.revenue(p.revenue), 
                 opt.profit = true.profit(p.profit)
                 %>% 
  nest_select(data, p.revenue, p.profit,opt.revenue,opt.profit) %>%
  unnest(data))
```

i get strange errors

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
x Problem with `summarise()` input `opt.profit`.
x no applicable method for 'pull' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
i Input `opt.profit` is ``%>%`(...)`.
i Input `data` is `purrr::map(...)`.
```

What do they mean? and What i do wrong? How can i correct run code.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Perhaps missed a ")" after "true.profit(p.profit)" ?? (and have extra ")" after unnest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two functions are using variables (`alpha`, `beta`, and `unity.cost`) but they are not passed to the function. While R allows this and often does what you expect, this is bad practice, and makes troubleshooting and maintenance more difficult. I suggest you change the functions to accept those variables as arguments.

Ultimately, you are missing a `)` closing out your `mutate` and have an extra `)` after your `unnest`.

Try this:

```r
p=dat$hist.prices
true.revenue = function(p, alpha, beta) p*(-alpha*p + beta) # Revenue with true parameters (chunck demand)
true.profit = function(p, alpha, beta, unity.cost) (p - unity.cost)*(-alpha*beta + 500) # price with true parameters

dat %>% 
  nest(data = -sku) %>% 
  nest_summarise(
    data, 
    model.fit = list(lm(hist.demand ~ hist.prices)), 
    beta = model.fit[[1]]$coefficients[1], 
    alpha = model.fit[[1]]$coefficients[2],
    p.revenue = -beta/(2*alpha),
    p.profit = (alpha*unity.cost - beta)/(2*alpha),
    opt.revenue = true.revenue(p.revenue, alpha, beta), 
    opt.profit = true.profit(p.profit, alpha, beta, unity.cost)
  ) %>% 
  nest_select(data, p.revenue, p.profit,opt.revenue,opt.profit) %>%
  unnest(data)
```

Comment: i tried. but something wrong  Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `data`.
x Problem with `summarise()` input `opt.revenue`.
x argument "alpha" is missing, with no default
i Input `opt.revenue` is `true.revenue(p.revenue)`.
i Input `data` is `purrr::map(...)`
does this solution work for your?